# Have installed php7 with wamp2.5, and Apache won't work

Tags: php, apache, wamp

At first place I installed

- wamp2.5 with apache2.4.9,
- php2.5.12,

and it worked well, but when I updated php to `7.0.3`, no matter how I tried to configure, it just couldn't work out.

And here is the error I've got:

```
Could not execute menu item (internal error) 
[Exception] Could not perform service action:
```

The service has not been started. Well, by the way, I don't get `80-port` unavailable issues, `80` is not already used.

Comment: do you have installed mysql in your pc? if yes, then it may use 80 port

Comment: Yes I've installed MySql, but it uses 3306 port, the 80 port is free and available but Apache doesn't work, but when I switch PHP back to 5.5.12 (sorry it's 5.5.12), and it works.